# Type not assignable (React + Typescript + Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication

I'm pretty new at typescript and migrating my react app to using ts.

I'm using the firebase auth service and I'm facing some type issues which I can't seem to get around. Please advise!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import app from './firebase';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      // ts error here
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setPending(false);
    });
  }, []);

  if(pending){
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      // ts error here
      value={{ currentUser }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
```

`setCurrentUser(user);` is giving me an error of 
`Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'.`

and

`value={{ currentUser }}` is giving me an error of `Type '{ currentUser: null; }' is not assignable to type 'null'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user parameter that returns from firebase ,it's type is not assignable to null,so you should create a type or interface for that use or you could just try to add 'any' like this:

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<any>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I added  to the context and it worked

```
export const AuthContext = createContext<any>(null)
```